# Value object serialization options

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I am coding a value object for my domain object identifier, similar to what is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18608975/1720077).  Basically I am just wrapping a guid.

By following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/20/how-to-bind-to-custom-objects-in-action-signatures-in-mvc-webapi.aspx?Redirected=true) article's advice I was able to create a custom model binder which can convert a string to the value object (for input to the controller), but I don't seem to be able to get the correct value as output from the controller.

My hope is to get something similar to this back from my controller action:

```
{
    id: "string representation of the guid goes here",
    someOtherProperty: "foo"
}
```

Has anyone done something similar, and if so, what am I missing?

**TenantId.cs**

```
    public class TenantId : IEquatable<TenantId>
    {
        public TenantId(Guid id)
        {
            if (id == Guid.Empty)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("TenantId must not be an empty GUID.");
            }
            _id = id;
        }

        private readonly Guid _id;

        public bool Equals(TenantId other)
        {
            if (null == other)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return _id.Equals(other._id);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return _id.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object other)
        {
            return Equals(other as TenantId);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _id.ToString("B");
        }

    }
}
```

**TenantIdModelBinder.cs**

```
public class TenantIdModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var key = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);

        if (val == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var s = val.AttemptedValue;
        if (s == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        Guid g;
        if (!Guid.TryParse(s, out g))
        {
            return false;
        }

        bindingContext.Model = new TenantId(g);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**TenantController.cs**

```
public class TenantController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get([ModelBinder(typeof(TenantIdModelBinder))]TenantId id)
    {
        return Ok(new
        {
            id
        });
    }
}
```

I can step through and see model is bound properly to the correct guid I pass in, however, this code simply returns: {"id":{}}

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: Posted per your request

Comment: You may try custom json converter, here is an expample: http://michaelcummings.net/mathoms/using-a-custom-jsonconverter-to-fix-bad-json-results

Comment: @Dima I was able to get it working with custom json converter.  If you want the points, can you create an answer for it?